# Drag & Drop files & folders on GNOME Window manager Launcher Icons

Tags: gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock, desktop-icons

I'm a new Ubuntu 18.04 user, but have been a Ubuntu user for years and used multiple desktop managers (GNOME, Unity, XFCE, etc.).

One feature that I loved about XFCE is that I could drop a file or a folder on a launcher icon and it would open the file/folder using the corresponding program (Visual Studio Code with a folder I dropped for example would open the folder, or dropping an image on GIMP would allow me to edit it). This feature does not seem to be present in GNOME with a default installation for Ubuntu 18.04.

Is there anyway to enable it, or is it not implemented and one would have to implement it manually?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment such a feature isn't implemented by Gnome and as far as I know Gnome has no plans to implement it in the near future. Also, I don't think that there is an extension that can provide this capability.